# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android render model vertices in single color?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm obviously an OpenGL poseur.

My goal is to have a custom Android GLSurfaceView control using GLES20 that can load an STL resource file (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) and render it in a single defined color with fixed lighting.
The model itself will rotate; the lighting and color will be fixed.

Sounds simple, but I cannot find a way to apply what I learn from the plethora of simple Triangle/Cube examples with a separate color on each face, to a model w/ 35k faces (not that the number of faces really matters).

I've borrowed this pretty decent code [that loads ascii STL files]...
https://bitbucket.org/saschawillems/opengl-es/src/ed3b324dda4b/stlviewer/?at=master
...and changed it to run in Android Studio and load binary STL files:
https://bitbucket.org/swooby/opengl-es/src/8bf43e1583c2/stlviewer/?at=binary

The renderer's shader code just computes a color using the face normals, which results in a cute rainbow effect with the illusion of being lit:
https://bitbucket.org/swooby/opengl-es/src/8bf43e1583c238f4397bc469b13cd60dcb34674b/stlviewer/app/src/main/java/de/saschawillems/stlviewer/GLES20Renderer.java?at=binary&fileviewer=file-view-default#GLES20Renderer.java-166
I take it to mean though that there is no real actual lighting going on here.

I must be missing something here, because I think that what I want to do is even simpler than computing colors from normals; I just want to draw the object using a single defined color shaded from the normals. I have tried to do this by setting the fragment color to a constant, but this results in a very 2D looking image/silhouette w/ no shadows.
I am fairly certain this requires adding lighting, and maybe this adds a tiny bit of code, but I am obviously such a poseur at this that I can't figure it even a complex way to do this.

I have searched all over the Googles for examples of what I want to do; I would think it would be and easy find, but I have been unable to find one. I am just looking for a simple classic "Teapot" example where the color can be defined.
Anyone willing to show me how I can code this up simply, or where can I find a simple example of what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Pv

Answer (score 0):

Currently you set the color to be the non transformed normal vector your have. Thus you are visualizing the normal components each fragment has.

To enable some very basic lighting, first you need to select where you want your light to be based. I would suggest the positive Z axis.

Then define a color via a uniform or a constant in the shader.

```
vec3 color = vec3(1.0,0.0,0.5);
```

Now, since you selected Z-axis, you can modify the color components by multiplying them with your normal z component:

```
vColor = vec4(color * aNormal[2], 1.0);
```

Most of the object will be black since normal components go from -1.0 to 1.0 and colors only from 0.0 to 1.0, to overcome this you can cheat a bit:

```
vColor = vec4(color * ((1.0 + aNormal[2]) / 2.0), 1.0);
```

Now you notice the light appears to be glued to the z axis of the model and not to the world. This is because you rotate the model, but not the normal. The simplest way to fix this is to apply your rotation matrix to the normal (you need to pass that as a uniform as well) before using it on the color component.

```
uniform mat4 uRotMatrix;
...
vec4 rotatedNormal=uRotMatrix * vec4(aNormal,1.0);
vColor = vec4(color * ((1.0 + rotatedNormal[2]) / 2.0), 1.0);
```

This gives you a directional light coming from the positive Z-axis.

If you want to have a custom position for the light, add more lights or add some specular lighting I suggest you read for example this [tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-8-basic-shading/). The amount of math increases a bit, but it keeps pretty simple.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks @mikkokoo! I'll give that a try. In the mean time I have been having luck using the Rajawali3d library, and had planned to reverse engineer the simplest raw OpenGLES2 code that I can to render a lit object and answer my question here. I find it odd that I cannot easily find a simple example like this already existing.